# Прокрутка горизонтального RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

В приложении есть горизонтальный RecyclerView в котором происходит выбор карточки ввиде карусельки где главный елемент занимает центральную позицию.
как можно сделать что бы при свайпе в сторону список не крутился на несколько елементов, а прокручивался только на один.
я пробовал использовать

```
 SnapHelper  snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper()
```

но к сожалению это не помогло решить проблему так.

Comment: PagerSnapHelper как вы добавили в recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

```
    val pagerSnapHelper = PagerSnapHelper()
    pagerSnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView)
```

Comment: как я писал в вопросе) это не работает )